# Parse date in android

Tags: java, android

I have the following code to pase a date

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
Date _pubDate =  df.parse(_pubDateE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```

But I get this error:

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 12 Aug 2011 15:34:47 CEST"

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the timezone in the date format at the end, in your exception message, the "CEST" part.
Your code

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

should be

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z", Locale.getDefault());
```

You might want to read [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Edit
At the bottom of this page, the timezone format is more cleary explained
[Clearer Timezone format](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/)

Comment: Ran my code with your error date in a junit test and it parsed your date fine, tried zzz also and it worked. My locale is EST, beware the constructor you're using might not support your locale. As per the javadoc : Note: This constructor may not support all locales. For full coverage, use the factory methods in the DateFormat class.

Comment: Hmm.. Strange... In Eclipse it works fine. But if I try it on my Galaxy 2 I get the error

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to add `zzz` in the end (for timezone):

```
"EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz"
```

Answer (score 0):

The date string is not in the format you specified. Notice the time zone at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want: `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz", Locale.getDefault());`