# How to parse date following format

Tags: android, nsdateformatter

How do parse this date format **Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016** to normal date, month and year format.

ex:

```
  String day = "Thu", 

  String month= "Dec", 

  String year= "2016"
```

Comment: what is `normal date, month and year format.`? have you tried using https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ?

Comment: @ Vlad Matvienko, That I know dude. I am expecting answer not command. I had given example know what is normal date.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I wish users like you, gives commands that have no help to nobody, will end one day. As I always say, everybody understands different, somebody wants this ready because they are dealing with other things at that moment so you can just give answer if you know or leave it blank to let other people answer it, do not give negative comments because this is NOYB --> "None Of Your Business" and they are not constructive, just destructive.

Comment: @webmaster, sorry, but people, who think that they can have others doing their job for free have to suffer.

Comment: @webmaster, You are teaching me not to teach others. Sorry, but where is the logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse date in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042961/parse-date-in-android)

Comment: @VladMatvienko you have anger inside you, let it free. This is a Q & A site, so deal with just Q & A please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String input = "Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date date = parser.parse(input);
```

You can get the needed data from date. Or as you demand:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
String dayOfWeek = dateFormat.format(date);//Thu

dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
String month = dateFormat.format(date);//Dec

dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String year = dateFormat.format(date);//2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String strDate = "";
 SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
 Date date= parser.parse(dateFromDB);

 String dayOfTheWeek = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", date);
 String stringMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", date); 
 String intMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM", date); 
 String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", date); 
 String day = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", date);
```

also check these links:
[Android date parsing (Extracting month and year )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417927/android-date-parsing-extracting-month-and-year)

[Get Value Of Day Month form Date Object in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192776/get-value-of-day-month-form-date-object-in-android)

[How to get the day, year, hours, min Individually from date format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551955/how-to-get-the-day-year-hours-min-individually-from-date-format-yyyy-mm-ddt)